# If a ransomware is currently encrypting my files, should I power off my computer?

Tags: ransomware, incident-response

I wondered what to do if there is a currently ongoing ransomware execution on my computer.

Assuming that I'm "spotting" it while it is encrypting my files, should I power my computer off?

I would say no because it would cancel any memory forensics operation, and maybe some files that are not properly encrypted would be permanently loss. But it would also "save" some of my files if they are not encrypted yet.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: Hibernate it so that you can extract its keys from the memory dump.

Comment: How slow / fast is this encryption?  Can a person act fast enough in "human time" for it to be worth it ?

Comment: @Stewart generally, as slow as a full backup. Or slower because ransomware authors don't bother with efficiency

Comment: @defalt "Good" ransomware will generate a new key for each file, so doing a memory dump will not allow decryption of any files except the one currently being encrypted.

Comment: There's a short answer and a long answer, and both of them say "you shouldn't care until you've a backup of your data". Make ALWAYS a backup of your data, and not only for ransomware; what will happen if the hard disk collapse? If you delete your own data? If a thief stole your PC?

Comment: @defalt The key will only be helpful if they use symmetric encryption on the file data. But hibernating will persist memory contents to disk, which is good for forensics – unless the ransomware is capable of detecting that your system is going into hibernation, and quickly covering up its tracks in response.

Comment: @user149408 They **always** use symmetric encryption on the files themselves. Asymmetric encryption is used only to encrypt the randomly-generated symmetric key. This is called a hybrid cryptosystem.

Comment: @forest I know the concept. This is mainly being done because the asymmetric encryption algorithms in use today are more computationally expensive than equally strong symmetric ones. But the ecosystem evolves, and what’s true today doesn’t have to be true tomorrow. Someday we may see an asymmetric algorithm that outperforms equally strong symmetric ones, and/or ransomware authors raising the bar as a result of an arms race between the good guys and the bad ones.

Comment: @user149408 It's also because asymmetric cryptography can only encrypt small chunks at a time. Asymmetric cryptography will never exceed the performance of symmetric cryptography for a wide variety of reasons ([crypto.se] has some questions on that subject).

Answer (score 13):

If you're infected, you should power off your system immediately. Failure to do so may result in more files being encrypted, lost, additional devices on your LAN being attacked and exploited, attacker hiding his work, etc. etc. etc.

After powering it down, you should *not* boot from this drive. The best way moving forward is to hand this drive over to forensics.

There's an argument for hibernating instead of just powering off because it will save the contents of RAM to your disk drive which then could be used to possibly find and extract the encryption key.

Comment: Is it possible that the encryption starts with MFT? Does malware not dare to mess with it in a live system?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "starts with MFT". You cannot encrypt it, it will make the system dead. Secondly, only the NT kernel can access it. Malware cannot do anything with it. You can access/modify this "file" for an *offline* volume which is *not* mounted.

Comment: @Lodinn Artem is correct, but missing a key point.  The whole goal of Ransomware is to convert your computer into a payment kiosk that promises to give you your files back if you pay.  If it wants to accomplish this, the machine needs to be able to boot when it makes its ransoms demands.  This means not encrypting/corrupting key files that are needed to recover data, including the bootloader.  Besides...  The writers know that lost data is what "sells".  An OS is easy to replace.